# Interfaces - solving ambiguous error

Tags: java, interface

Lets look at the following example:

```
public class BothPaintAndPrintable implements Paintable,Printable{
    public void print() {}
    public void paint() {}
}
public interface Paintable {
    public void paint();
}

public interface Printable {
    public void print();
}

public class ITest {
    ArrayList<Printable> printables = new ArrayList<Printable>();
    ArrayList<Paintable> paintables = new ArrayList<Paintable>();
    public void add(Paintable p) {
        paintables.add(p);
    }
    public void add(Printable p) {
        printables.add(p);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BothPaintAndPrintable a= new BothPaintAndPrintable();
        ITest t=new ITest();
        t.add(a);//compiliation error here
    }
}
```

What if I want `BothPaintAndPrintable` instances to be added to each of the ArrayLists?
One way would be overloading the method with a `BothPaintAndPrintable` parameter, but I'm trying to see alternatives since doing that might reduce code reuseability. Does anyone have another idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need a third overload:

```
public <T extends Object&Paintable&Printable> void add(T t) {
  paintables.add(t);
  printables.add(t);
}
```

This makes the erasure `add(Object)`, so it doesn't conflict with the other methods, but it does restrict the input to implementors of both `Paintable` and `Printable`.

(Guava [had to use this trick](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Joiner.html#appendTo%28A,%20I%29) for `Joiner` with `Iterator` and `Iterable`, because some evil classes out there implemented both, even though it's a terrible idea.)

Comment: Thought of this, too. But it has the same erasure like the other add methods then. So now we have a compile error there.

Comment: this is even worse then adding a add(BothPaintAndPrintable p) overload is it not?

Comment: In what way is it "even worse"?  It's the only way to do it without forcing users to remember to implement an extra interface.  It doesn't require any extra effort from callers, or from classes that implement both `Paintable` and `Printable`.

Comment: this is more complex and has the same effect as overloading add with a BothPaintAndPrintable param... correct me if im wrong..

Comment: This doesn't actually need you to specify which classes are both `Paintable` and `Printable` up front.  It just works for _any_ class that implements both `Paintable` and `Printable`.

Comment: @OfekRon, this solution has no coupling between your ITest and BothPaintAndPrintable classes. It also makes it so any class implementations that implement both the Paintable and Printable interfaces but are not BothPaintAndPrintable Objects will work properly.

Comment: @OfekRon But then you've to overload it again and again for every class imlementing both interfaces. Or you've to define an interface extending the two interfaces, but then it comes into play what Louis said that everybody have to remeber to implement this "combined interface".

Comment: btw: I must somewhat make sure to remember this `Object &` trick. Did not know about it.

Comment: And what about classes that dont implement the Printable nor the Paintable interfaces but do extends Object, since that method is  suitable for them, are they not get added to the lists?

Comment: @OfekRon They are not suitable. Only objects matching all three types are suitable. While matching Object type is tautologic in java this trick works.

Comment: oh i get it, we gain the fact that we dont have to make a new Interface for each comibination of the interfaces?

Comment: That's correct.  At _compile time_, this forces you to pass objects implementing `Paintable`, `Printable`, or both.

Comment: One possible downside is that you only can perform this `Object &` trick once, am I right? So having a third interface `Drawable` and a add-method for `Printable` and `Drawable` is not possible, right? Because they both have the same erasure `add(Object)`.

Comment: That's correct, though I'd personally call it a "limitation" rather than a "downside."

Answer (score 2):

I would go with a general `add(Object o)` method, then checking for `instanceof`, and putting the `Object` into the according lists.

If the passed `Object` implements neither interface, throwing an `InvalidArgumentException` might be a good idea.

Comment: Not a good idea. Always do checking at compile time when possible.

Comment: @PaulBellora - When possible, sure.  I'll leave the answer standing until an obviously better idea comes around. Hopefully it does.

Comment: Louis Wasserman's answer is great. I'll leave mine here for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the best answer as I can't find a way I actually like!

You could use generics, but I don't like either the "instanceof" tests, nor the casts required:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

class BothPaintAndPrintable implements Paintable, Printable {
    public void print() {
    }

    public void paint() {
    }
}

interface Paintable {
    public void paint();
}

interface Printable {
    public void print();
}

 public class ITest<T> {
    ArrayList<Printable> printables = new ArrayList<Printable>();

    ArrayList<Paintable> paintables = new ArrayList<Paintable>();

    public void add(T p) {
        if (p instanceof Paintable) {
            paintables.add((Paintable) p);
        }
        if (p instanceof Printable) {
            printables.add((Printable) p);
        }
    } 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BothPaintAndPrintable a = new BothPaintAndPrintable();
        ITest<BothPaintAndPrintable> t = new ITest<BothPaintAndPrintable>();
        t.add(a);
    }
}
```

Comment: What Louis Wasserman answered above fixes what I didn't like about the solution above.  You can't just overload the methods though - java will complain about the methods having the same erasure...

Comment: .. Louis corrected his solution with the `Object &` trick. Now it compiles and is the best solution possible afaik.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I do like the correct answer; however, there is another solution I should point out to the OP.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BothPaintAndPrintable a= new BothPaintAndPrintable();
    ITest t=new ITest();
    t.add((Paintable)a);
    t.add((Printable)a);
}
```

This works without adding the third member, and even works if you decide to add more interfaces down the road.